# Use a PPA with a Password while still using Apt-cacher-ng?

Tags: ppa, apt, apt-cacher-ng

I'm using apt-cacher-ng to cache package downloads for my LAN. I'm also using the Ubuntu Beta fonts PPA which requires a password for access. I keep getting the error

```
bjorn@bjorn-laptop-natty:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for bjorn: 
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty InRelease
<snip>                      
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net natty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex      
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net natty/main TranslationIndex    
Err https://private-ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources             
  Failed to connect to 0.0.7.209: Invalid argument
Err https://private-ppa.launchpad.net natty/main amd64 Packages                
  Failed to connect to 0.0.7.209: Invalid argument
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en_US             
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty Release.gpg                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates Release.gpg                     
<snip>       
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe Translation-en          
Fetched 72 B in 7s (10 B/s)                                                    
W: Failed to fetch https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-font-beta-testing/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources  Failed to connect to 0.0.7.209: Invalid argument

W: Failed to fetch https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-font-beta-testing/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Failed to connect to 0.0.7.209: Invalid argument

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

It works properly if I disable using apt-cacher-ng. It seems weird that it says that it is trying to connect to 0.0.7.209; I'm pretty sure that's not the address of launchpad's PPAs. I don't always want to be changing settings just to check for updates, so how can I make apt-cacher-ng and a passworded PPA work together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can bypass apt-cacher-ng for certain hosts by using lines like the following in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or the configuration file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`

`Acquire::HTTP::Proxy::archive.example.org "DIRECT";`